# repeat functions in jquery based on variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a group of Images in a webpage with each one has it's own ID, all of the ID's saved in a php array. I want to write a script where it take the ID from the php array and pass it to the client side and repeat a certain jquery function for each image. Here what I did:

```
<script>
    <? php for ($i = 0; $i < $counterPostID; $i++) {
        $str = "#post".$arrID[$i]; ?>
        var myvar = <? php echo json_encode($str); ?> ;
        var myvar2 = myvar + " " + "#textcaption";

        //functions to be repeated for each image
        jQuery(myvar).mouseover(function() {
            jQuery(myvar2).slideDown("slow");
        }).mouseout(function() {
            jQuery(myvar2).slideUp("slow");
        });

    <? php } ?>
</script>
```

The code work fine but only for the last occurrence in the loop, I want the jQuery code to be repeated for all the images. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post generated HTML that will help. You can use common class to achieve this

Comment: You are right! common class is a valid solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$counterPostID` is an array with all the ID's, you can just implode it to a selector

```
var selector = '<?php echo "#post" . implode(", #post", $counterPostID); ?>';
// should output something like -> '#postid1, #postid2, #postid3' ... etc

$(selector).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $('.textcaption', this).slideToggle('slow'); // use a class, not the same ID
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because you're overwriting your vars with each loop. You could output the entire array to javascript and loop through it client-side, but you don't have to. I would recommend giving your posts a class, and giving your `#textcaption` elements a class, since `id`s must be unique, and targeting the classes:

```
jQuery('.post').mouseover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.textcaption').slideDown("slow");
}).mouseout(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.textcaption').slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: worked fine, I did not notice the overwriting of the vars. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the **SAME** ID over and over:

```
#post1 #textcaption
#post2 #textcaption
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^--- here
etc..
```

IDs can occur only **ONCE** in a DOM document. Since an ID must be unique, `document.getElementById()` (which is what jquery is using internally, basically) will only ever return a single DOM element, never a list. That means the **FIRST** id found is what will be returned/processed.

Plus, your code will generate highly repetitive JS. Why not simply pass your IDs as an array to JS, then loop on that array? e.g.

```
<script>
   var IDs = <?php echo json_encode($arrID); ?>;
   $.each(IDs, function(idx, valu) {
      ... do your mouseover/mouseout stuff here ..
   });
</script>
```